# Find similarities in nested objects

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have:

```js
const a = {
  'prkn': {
    tec: [ 'Coding', 'Machine Learning', 'Cloud Development' ],
    des: [ 'Web Design' ]
  },
  'pekn': { cu: [ 'Musica', 'Cinema', 'Arte' ] }
}

const b = {
  'prkn': {
    tec: [
      'Coding',
      'Machine Learning',
      'Cloud Development',
      'IoT Management'
    ],
    des: [ 'UX/UI', 'Web Design', 'Prototyping', 'Design Thinking' ]
  },
  'pekn': { cu: [ 'Cinema', 'Lettura' ] }
}
```

and I want the intersection of these objects:

```js
{
  'prkn': {
    tec: [ 'Coding', 'Machine Learning', 'Cloud Development' ],
    des: [ 'Web Design' ]
  },
  'pekn': { cu: [ 'Cinema' ] }
}
```

Here the code, but it doesn't work..:

```js
const a = {
  'prkn': {
    tec: [ 'Coding', 'Machine Learning', 'Cloud Development' ],
    des: [ 'Web Design' ]
  },
  'pekn': { cu: [ 'Musica', 'Cinema', 'Arte' ] }
}

const b = {
  'prkn': {
    tec: [
      'Coding',
      'Machine Learning',
      'Cloud Development',
      'IoT Management'
    ],
    des: [ 'UX/UI', 'Web Design', 'Prototyping', 'Design Thinking' ]
  },
  'pekn': { cu: [ 'Cinema', 'Lettura' ] }
}

function findSimilarities(obj1, obj2) {
  const bo1 = Object.entries(obj1).reduce((acc1, [l1, v1]) => {
    const bo2 = Object.entries(v1).reduce((acc2, [l2, v2]) => {
      const sim = v2.filter(s => obj2[l1][l2].includes(s))
      acc2[l2] = sim
      return acc2
    })
    acc1[l1] = bo2
    return acc1
  }, {})
 return bo1
}

console.log(findSimilarities(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly straightforward example that works for your given data.

It first intersects the `Object.keys()` of the passed objects and filters them based on the `typeof` the properties they are associated with so we don't waste time comparing keys that aren't shared or whose types don't match. It then iterates over these keys, if they reference objects (but not arrays) it recurses, else if both are arrays intersect them (here using `includes()` so nested objects won't work), finally check basic equality. Set the `acc[key]` and return.

```js
const
  a = { 'prkn': { red: 1, bl: null, tec: ['Coding', 'Machine Learning', 'Cloud Development'], des: ['Web Design'] }, 'pekn': { cu: ['Musica', 'Cinema', 'Arte'] } },
  b = { 'prkn': { red: 1, bl: 'Dog', tec: ['Coding', 'Machine Learning', 'Cloud Development', 'IoT Management'], des: ['UX/UI', 'Web Design', 'Prototyping', 'Design Thinking'] }, 'pekn': { cu: ['Cinema', 'Lettura'] } },

  intersectPrimitiveArrays = (a, b) => a.filter(e => b.includes(e)),

  intersectObjects = (a, b) => {
    const keys = intersectPrimitiveArrays(Object.keys(a), Object.keys(b))
      .filter(k => (typeof a[k]) === (typeof b[k]));

    return keys.reduce((acc, key) => {
      const
        _a = a[key],
        _b = b[key];

      let element = _a;

      if (typeof _a === 'object' && (_a !== null || _b !== null) && (!Array.isArray(_a) && !Array.isArray(_b))) {
        element = intersectObjects(_a, _b);
      } else if (Array.isArray(_a) && Array.isArray(_b)) {
        element = intersectPrimitiveArrays(_a, _b);
      } else if (_a !== _b) {
        element = undefined;
      }

      if (element !== undefined) {
        acc[key] = element;
      }

      return acc;
    }, {})
  }

console.log(intersectObjects(a, b));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```